# Getting com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail While building via TeamCity

Tags: java, linux, devops, continuous-deployment, teamcity-9.0

I am trying to SSH the remote server through Teamcity 9. Its gives following error while doing SSH. Runner type is SSH exec.I have also added the public key of Teamcity 9(Linux Based box) in the authorized_keys of the remote server. Please help me to come out of this issue.

```
 com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:512)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.deployer.agent.ssh.SSHSessionProvider.<init>(SSHSessionProvider.java:86)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.deployer.agent.ssh.SSHExecRunner.createBuildProcess(SSHExecRunner.java:26)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.runner.CallRunnerService.doCreateBuildProcess(CallRunnerService.java:71)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.runner.CallRunnerService.createBuildProcess(CallRunnerService.java:47)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.runnerStages.start.CallRunnerStage.doBuildStage(CallRunnerStage.java:47)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.RunnerStagesExecutor$1.callStage(RunnerStagesExecutor.java:25)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.RunnerStagesExecutor$1.callStage(RunnerStagesExecutor.java:18)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.callRunStage(StagesExecutor.java:78)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.doStages(StagesExecutor.java:37)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.RunnerStagesExecutor.doStages(RunnerStagesExecutor.java:18)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.RunnerContextExecutor.callRunnerStages(RunnerContextExecutor.java:43)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.StepExecutor.processNextStep(StepExecutor.java:25)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.ForEachBuildRunnerStage.executeRunnerStep(ForEachBuildRunnerStage.java:138)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.ForEachBuildRunnerStage.runStep(ForEachBuildRunnerStage.java:123)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.ForEachBuildRunnerStage.executeBuildRunners(ForEachBuildRunnerStage.java:83)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.ForEachBuildRunnerStage.doBuildStage(ForEachBuildRunnerStage.java:44)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor$1.callStage(BuildStagesExecutor.java:31)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor$1.callStage(BuildStagesExecutor.java:24)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.callRunStage(StagesExecutor.java:78)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.doStages(StagesExecutor.java:37)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor.doStages(BuildStagesExecutor.java:24)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildRunActionImpl.doStages(BuildRunActionImpl.java:70)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildRunActionImpl.runBuild(BuildRunActionImpl.java:50)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl.doActualBuild(BuildAgentImpl.java:288)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl.access$100(BuildAgentImpl.java:53)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl$1.run(BuildAgentImpl.java:252)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Teamcity is on Linux and remote server where TeamCity is trying for SSH is also on Linux.
```